# Empty data context generated from nuget package install

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, nuget

I have created a nuget package that has an EF6 data model. I have another solution with projects where I have installed that nuget package. Immediately after installing/updating the nuget package I get an exception message in the error list in the console for each of the projects.

The exception message is

`Running transformation: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate file` referring to DataModel.Context.tt.

The error is thrown at

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.ResolvePath(String path)`

The exception message gets resolved when Visual Studio automatically creates the "missing" files. It just takes a really long time when I have multiple contexts being consumed by multiple projects with that nuget package installed and they are not needed. I even delete the files and build the project just fine.

The DataModel.Context.tt and DataModel.tt files are auto-generated and they make empty .cs files.

This is the Context.tt file:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ include file="EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@
 output extension=".cs"#><#

const string inputFile = @"DataModel.edmx";
var textTransform = DynamicTextTransformation.Create(this);
var code = new CodeGenerationTools(this);
var ef = new MetadataTools(this);
var typeMapper = new TypeMapper(code, ef, textTransform.Errors);
var loader = new EdmMetadataLoader(textTransform.Host, textTransform.Errors);
var itemCollection = loader.CreateEdmItemCollection(inputFile);
var modelNamespace = loader.GetModelNamespace(inputFile);
var codeStringGenerator = new CodeStringGenerator(code, typeMapper, ef);

var container = itemCollection.OfType<EntityContainer>().FirstOrDefault();
if (container == null)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
#>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine1")#>
//
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine2")#>
// <#=CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_GeneratedCodeCommentLine3")#>
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<#

var codeNamespace = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(codeNamespace))
{
#>
namespace <#=code.EscapeNamespace(codeNamespace)#>
{
<#
    PushIndent("    ");
}

#>
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
<#
if (container.FunctionImports.Any())
{
#>
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Linq;
<#
}
#>

<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()
        : base("name=<#=container.Name#>")
    {
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}

foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
    // Note: the DbSet members are defined below such that the getter and
    // setter always have the same accessibility as the DbSet definition
    if (Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet) != "public")
    {
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSetInitializer(entitySet)#>
<#
    }
}
#>
    }

    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(String nameOrConnectionString)
    : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}

foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
    // Note: the DbSet members are defined below such that the getter and
    // setter always have the same accessibility as the DbSet definition
    if (Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet) != "public")
    {
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSetInitializer(entitySet)#>
<#
    }
}
#>
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

<#
    foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
    {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSet(entitySet)#>
<#
    }

    foreach (var edmFunction in container.FunctionImports)
    {
        WriteFunctionImport(typeMapper, codeStringGenerator, edmFunction, modelNamespace, includeMergeOption: false);
    }
#>
}
<#

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(codeNamespace))
{
    PopIndent();
#>
}
<#
}
#>
<#+

private void WriteFunctionImport(TypeMapper typeMapper, CodeStringGenerator codeStringGenerator, EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)
{
    if (typeMapper.IsComposable(edmFunction))
    {
#>

    [DbFunction("<#=edmFunction.NamespaceName#>", "<#=edmFunction.Name#>")]
    <#=codeStringGenerator.ComposableFunctionMethod(edmFunction, modelNamespace)#>
    {
<#+
        codeStringGenerator.WriteFunctionParameters(edmFunction, WriteFunctionParameter);
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.ComposableCreateQuery(edmFunction, modelNamespace)#>
    }
<#+
    }
    else
    {
#>

    <#=codeStringGenerator.FunctionMethod(edmFunction, modelNamespace, includeMergeOption)#>
    {
<#+
        codeStringGenerator.WriteFunctionParameters(edmFunction, WriteFunctionParameter);
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.ExecuteFunction(edmFunction, modelNamespace, includeMergeOption)#>
    }
<#+
        if (typeMapper.GenerateMergeOptionFunction(edmFunction, includeMergeOption))
        {
            WriteFunctionImport(typeMapper, codeStringGenerator, edmFunction, modelNamespace, includeMergeOption: true);
        }
    }
}

public void WriteFunctionParameter(string name, string isNotNull, string notNullInit, string nullInit)
{
#>
        var <#=name#> = <#=isNotNull#> ?
            <#=notNullInit#> :
            <#=nullInit#>;

<#+
}

public const string TemplateId = "CSharp_DbContext_Context_EF6";

public class CodeStringGenerator
{
    private readonly CodeGenerationTools _code;
    private readonly TypeMapper _typeMapper;
    private readonly MetadataTools _ef;

    public CodeStringGenerator(CodeGenerationTools code, TypeMapper typeMapper, MetadataTools ef)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(code, "code");
        ArgumentNotNull(typeMapper, "typeMapper");
        ArgumentNotNull(ef, "ef");

        _code = code;
        _typeMapper = typeMapper;
        _ef = ef;
    }

    public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
            Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
            _code.Escape(edmProperty),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
    }

    public string NavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navProp)
    {
        var endType = _typeMapper.GetTypeName(navProp.ToEndMember.GetEntityType());
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForNavigationProperty(navProp)),
            navProp.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many ? ("ICollection<" + endType + ">") : endType,
            _code.Escape(navProp),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(navProp)),
            _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(navProp)));
    }

    public string AccessibilityAndVirtual(string accessibility)
    {
        return accessibility + (accessibility != "private" ? " virtual" : "");
    }

    public string EntityClassOpening(EntityType entity)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1}partial class {2}{3}",
            Accessibility.ForType(entity),
            _code.SpaceAfter(_code.AbstractOption(entity)),
            _code.Escape(entity),
            _code.StringBefore(" : ", _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entity.BaseType)));
    }

    public string EnumOpening(SimpleType enumType)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} enum {1} : {2}",
            Accessibility.ForType(enumType),
            _code.Escape(enumType),
            _code.Escape(_typeMapper.UnderlyingClrType(enumType)));
        }

    public void WriteFunctionParameters(EdmFunction edmFunction, Action<string, string, string, string> writeParameter)
    {
        var parameters = FunctionImportParameter.Create(edmFunction.Parameters, _code, _ef);
        foreach (var parameter in parameters.Where(p => p.NeedsLocalVariable))
        {
            var isNotNull = parameter.IsNullableOfT ? parameter.FunctionParameterName + ".HasValue" : parameter.FunctionParameterName + " != null";
            var notNullInit = "new ObjectParameter(\"" + parameter.EsqlParameterName + "\", " + parameter.FunctionParameterName + ")";
            var nullInit = "new ObjectParameter(\"" + parameter.EsqlParameterName + "\", typeof(" + TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(parameter.RawClrTypeName) + "))";
            writeParameter(parameter.LocalVariableName, isNotNull, notNullInit, nullInit);
        }
    }

    public string ComposableFunctionMethod(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} IQueryable<{1}> {2}({3})",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForMethod(edmFunction)),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(_typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction), modelNamespace),
            _code.Escape(edmFunction),
            string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(p.FunctionParameterType) + " " + p.FunctionParameterName).ToArray()));
    }

    public string ComposableCreateQuery(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<{0}>(\"[{1}].[{2}]({3})\"{4});",
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(_typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction), modelNamespace),
            edmFunction.NamespaceName,
            edmFunction.Name,
            string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => "@" + p.EsqlParameterName).ToArray()),
            _code.StringBefore(", ", string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ExecuteParameterName).ToArray())));
    }

    public string FunctionMethod(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);
        var returnType = _typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction);

        var paramList = String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => TypeMapper.FixNamespaces(p.FunctionParameterType) + " " + p.FunctionParameterName).ToArray());
        if (includeMergeOption)
        {
            paramList = _code.StringAfter(paramList, ", ") + "MergeOption mergeOption";
        }

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} {1} {2}({3})",
            AccessibilityAndVirtual(Accessibility.ForMethod(edmFunction)),
            returnType == null ? "int" : "ObjectResult<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
            _code.Escape(edmFunction),
            paramList);
    }

    public string ExecuteFunction(EdmFunction edmFunction, string modelNamespace, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var parameters = _typeMapper.GetParameters(edmFunction);
        var returnType = _typeMapper.GetReturnType(edmFunction);

        var callParams = _code.StringBefore(", ", String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => p.ExecuteParameterName).ToArray()));
        if (includeMergeOption)
        {
            callParams = ", mergeOption" + callParams;
        }

        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction{0}(\"{1}\"{2});",
            returnType == null ? "" : "<" + _typeMapper.GetTypeName(returnType, modelNamespace) + ">",
            edmFunction.Name,
            callParams);
    }

    public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} virtual DbSet<{1}> {2} {{ get; set; }}",
            Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType),
            _code.Escape(entitySet));
    }

    public string DbSetInitializer(EntitySet entitySet)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0} = Set<{1}>();",
            _code.Escape(entitySet),
            _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType));
    }

    public string UsingDirectives(bool inHeader, bool includeCollections = true)
    {
        return inHeader == string.IsNullOrEmpty(_code.VsNamespaceSuggestion())
            ? string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0}using System;{1}" +
                "{2}",
                inHeader ? Environment.NewLine : "",
                includeCollections ? (Environment.NewLine + "using System.Collections.Generic;") : "",
                inHeader ? "" : Environment.NewLine)
            : "";
    }
}

public class TypeMapper
{
    private const string ExternalTypeNameAttributeName = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration:ExternalTypeName";

    private readonly System.Collections.IList _errors;
    private readonly CodeGenerationTools _code;
    private readonly MetadataTools _ef;

    public static string FixNamespaces(string typeName)
    {
        return typeName.Replace("System.Data.Spatial.", "System.Data.Entity.Spatial.");
    }

    public TypeMapper(CodeGenerationTools code, MetadataTools ef, System.Collections.IList errors)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(code, "code");
        ArgumentNotNull(ef, "ef");
        ArgumentNotNull(errors, "errors");

        _code = code;
        _ef = ef;
        _errors = errors;
    }

    public string GetTypeName(TypeUsage typeUsage)
    {
        return typeUsage == null ? null : GetTypeName(typeUsage.EdmType, _ef.IsNullable(typeUsage), modelNamespace: null);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType)
    {
        return GetTypeName(edmType, isNullable: null, modelNamespace: null);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(TypeUsage typeUsage, string modelNamespace)
    {
        return typeUsage == null ? null : GetTypeName(typeUsage.EdmType, _ef.IsNullable(typeUsage), modelNamespace);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType, string modelNamespace)
    {
        return GetTypeName(edmType, isNullable: null, modelNamespace: modelNamespace);
    }

    public string GetTypeName(EdmType edmType, bool? isNullable, string modelNamespace)
    {
        if (edmType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var collectionType = edmType as CollectionType;
        if (collectionType != null)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "ICollection<{0}>", GetTypeName(collectionType.TypeUsage, modelNamespace));
        }

        var typeName = _code.Escape(edmType.MetadataProperties
                                .Where(p => p.Name == ExternalTypeNameAttributeName)
                                .Select(p => (string)p.Value)
                                .FirstOrDefault())
            ?? (modelNamespace != null && edmType.NamespaceName != modelNamespace ?
                _code.CreateFullName(_code.EscapeNamespace(edmType.NamespaceName), _code.Escape(edmType)) :
                _code.Escape(edmType));

        if (edmType is StructuralType)
        {
            return typeName;
        }

        if (edmType is SimpleType)
        {
            var clrType = UnderlyingClrType(edmType);
            if (!IsEnumType(edmType))
            {
                typeName = _code.Escape(clrType);
            }

            typeName = FixNamespaces(typeName);

            return clrType.IsValueType && isNullable == true ?
                String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Nullable<{0}>", typeName) :
                typeName;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("edmType");
    }

    public Type UnderlyingClrType(EdmType edmType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmType, "edmType");

        var primitiveType = edmType as PrimitiveType;
        if (primitiveType != null)
        {
            return primitiveType.ClrEquivalentType;
        }

        if (IsEnumType(edmType))
        {
            return GetEnumUnderlyingType(edmType).ClrEquivalentType;
        }

        return typeof(object);
    }

    public object GetEnumMemberValue(MetadataItem enumMember)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumMember, "enumMember");

        var valueProperty = enumMember.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
        return valueProperty == null ? null : valueProperty.GetValue(enumMember, null);
    }

    public string GetEnumMemberName(MetadataItem enumMember)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumMember, "enumMember");

        var nameProperty = enumMember.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
        return nameProperty == null ? null : (string)nameProperty.GetValue(enumMember, null);
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetEnumMembers(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        var membersProperty = enumType.GetType().GetProperty("Members");
        return membersProperty != null 
            ? (System.Collections.IEnumerable)membersProperty.GetValue(enumType, null)
            : Enumerable.Empty<MetadataItem>();
    }

    public bool EnumIsFlags(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        var isFlagsProperty = enumType.GetType().GetProperty("IsFlags");
        return isFlagsProperty != null && (bool)isFlagsProperty.GetValue(enumType, null);
    }

    public bool IsEnumType(GlobalItem edmType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmType, "edmType");

        return edmType.GetType().Name == "EnumType";
    }

    public PrimitiveType GetEnumUnderlyingType(EdmType enumType)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(enumType, "enumType");

        return (PrimitiveType)enumType.GetType().GetProperty("UnderlyingType").GetValue(enumType, null);
    }

    public string CreateLiteral(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(TimeSpan))
        {
            return _code.CreateLiteral(value);
        }

        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "new TimeSpan({0})", ((TimeSpan)value).Ticks);
    }

    public bool VerifyCaseInsensitiveTypeUniqueness(IEnumerable<string> types, string sourceFile)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(types, "types");
        ArgumentNotNull(sourceFile, "sourceFile");

        var hash = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (types.Any(item => !hash.Add(item)))
        {
            _errors.Add(
                new CompilerError(sourceFile, -1, -1, "6023",
                    String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_CaseInsensitiveTypeConflict"))));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SimpleType> GetEnumItemsToGenerate(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection)
    {
        return GetItemsToGenerate<SimpleType>(itemCollection)
            .Where(e => IsEnumType(e));
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetItemsToGenerate<T>(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection) where T: EdmType
    {
        return itemCollection
            .OfType<T>()
            .Where(i => !i.MetadataProperties.Any(p => p.Name == ExternalTypeNameAttributeName))
            .OrderBy(i => i.Name);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllGlobalItems(IEnumerable<GlobalItem> itemCollection)
    {
        return itemCollection
            .Where(i => i is EntityType || i is ComplexType || i is EntityContainer || IsEnumType(i))
            .Select(g => GetGlobalItemName(g));
    }

    public string GetGlobalItemName(GlobalItem item)
    {
        if (item is EdmType)
        {
            return ((EdmType)item).Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((EntityContainer)item).Name;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetSimpleProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetSimpleProperties(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetComplexProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetComplexProperties(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType && p.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type && p.DefaultValue != null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetPropertiesWithDefaultValues(ComplexType type)
    {
        return type.Properties.Where(p => p.TypeUsage.EdmType is SimpleType && p.DeclaringType == type && p.DefaultValue != null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetNavigationProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == type);
    }

    public IEnumerable<NavigationProperty> GetCollectionNavigationProperties(EntityType type)
    {
        return type.NavigationProperties.Where(np => np.DeclaringType == type && np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many);
    }

    public FunctionParameter GetReturnParameter(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmFunction, "edmFunction");

        var returnParamsProperty = edmFunction.GetType().GetProperty("ReturnParameters");
        return returnParamsProperty == null
            ? edmFunction.ReturnParameter
            : ((IEnumerable<FunctionParameter>)returnParamsProperty.GetValue(edmFunction, null)).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public bool IsComposable(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        ArgumentNotNull(edmFunction, "edmFunction");

        var isComposableProperty = edmFunction.GetType().GetProperty("IsComposableAttribute");
        return isComposableProperty != null && (bool)isComposableProperty.GetValue(edmFunction, null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<FunctionImportParameter> GetParameters(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        return FunctionImportParameter.Create(edmFunction.Parameters, _code, _ef);
    }

    public TypeUsage GetReturnType(EdmFunction edmFunction)
    {
        var returnParam = GetReturnParameter(edmFunction);
        return returnParam == null ? null : _ef.GetElementType(returnParam.TypeUsage);
    }

    public bool GenerateMergeOptionFunction(EdmFunction edmFunction, bool includeMergeOption)
    {
        var returnType = GetReturnType(edmFunction);
        return !includeMergeOption && returnType != null && returnType.EdmType.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType;
    }
}

public static void ArgumentNotNull<T>(T arg, string name) where T : class
{
    if (arg == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
}
#>
```

Anyone know how I can stop those files from being generated?

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to exclude the .tt files from the nuget package. I passed `-Exclude ***.tt` as a param in the `nuget pack` command.

Comment: Not even setting the Build Action on the .tt file(s) seems to work; passing the above seems to be required.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the Properties of the .tt-files in the nuget project and change the **Build Action** from **Content** to **None**.

Comment: Ran into this issue again and once again the above wasn't sufficient for me. The `-Exclude ***.tt` appeared to be required.

Comment: If I do what you say. An exception is thrown:

MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.